# How to delete in-place items in arrays in a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I used the following line:

```
list_split_test_array = np.split(test_array, np.where(test_array == 0.)[0])
```

to split an array at each 0., a value that I arbitrarily added previously as a place holder.
This gives me a list of arrays where the 0th index of each array (except for the first array) is a 0.
How do I delete these 0's in-place, to get a list of arrays without the placeholder 0's? I say in-place because I'd rather not iterate through, adding each array with the deleted 0 to a new array list.

Comment: Are those nested lists all the same length (except the 1st)?  If so, you could add a `0` to the 1st, cast it as a 2d array, and delete the 1st column.

Comment: I thought about that. Unfortunately no. I would ultimately like to have the output be a DataFrame where each column is an array from this list. If it's in that form, I think I should be able to do what you suggested, but I'm still working on getting into a df format

Comment: Iterating through and doing `[item[1:] for item in array_list]` is quite fast. It doesn't copy the arrays.  It's basically what you're asking for. You can't actually delete an item from a numpy array in-place. If you want to view everything except the first item without making a copy, though, just do `item[1:]` (as above).

Answer (score 1):

You can use some preprocess to remove zeros, here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 5, 100)
idx = np.where(a == 0)[0]

np.split(a, idx)
```

output:

```
[array([4, 3]),
 array([0, 3, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 4]),
 array([0]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 4]),
 array([0, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1]),
 array([0, 2, 4, 3]),
 array([0, 2, 2, 4]),
 array([0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2]),
 array([0]),
 array([0]),
 array([0, 1, 3]),
 array([0]),
 array([0, 1, 3, 2, 4]),
 array([0, 3, 3]),
 array([0, 3]),
 array([0, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1]),
 array([0]),
 array([0, 3, 2]),
 array([0]),
 array([0, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1]),
 array([0, 4]),
 array([0]),
 array([0]),
 array([0, 3, 4, 2, 3]),
 array([0, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1]),
 array([0, 2, 4, 1]),
 array([0, 4, 2, 2]),
 array([0])]
```

remove all zeros in `a`, and calculate the new index:

```
idx2 = idx - np.arange(len(idx))
b = np.delete(a, idx)
np.split(b, np.unique(idx2))
```

Here is the output:

```
[array([4, 3]),
 array([3, 1, 1]),
 array([4]),
 array([1, 2, 4]),
 array([4, 2, 2, 3, 1]),
 array([2, 4, 3]),
 array([2, 2, 4]),
 array([3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2]),
 array([1, 3]),
 array([1, 3, 2, 4]),
 array([3, 3]),
 array([3]),
 array([3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1]),
 array([3, 2]),
 array([4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1]),
 array([4]),
 array([3, 4, 2, 3]),
 array([4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1]),
 array([2, 4, 1]),
 array([4, 2, 2]),
 array([], dtype=float64)]
```

Comment: I ended up doing it with pandas DataFrames. Turns out I didn't need all the splitting and cleaning, but thanks for the help, and nice solution to the problem!